# how to split a string by ignoring the white space

Tags: java

```
 public class TestBoolean { 

     public static void main(String[] args) { 

         String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 

         String[] b = a.split("999"); 
         for (String c : b) { 
             System.out.println("Value\t:" + c); 
         } 

     } 
 }
```

I need output as

```
 13131300100 999 
 13131300200 999 
 13131300300 999 
 13131300400 999
```

Comment: Try to use http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Joiner

Comment: There is a close vote giving reason `unclear what is asking`, I am not sure that voter at least read the question. Since there is nothing can't understand in this question who has vote permission to close the questions. That kind of careless behavior harm the reputation of the `stackOverFlow`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example you could change your split regex to something like this:

```
String[] b = a.split("\\s(?!999)");
```

This will match:

1. first \\s - A whitespace character
2. (?!999) - not followed by 999.

Output:

```
Value   :13131300100 999
Value   :13131300200 999
Value   :13131300300 999
Value   :13131300400 999
```

The regex character classes can be found on the documentation for [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 

    String[] b = a.split(" "); 
    int len = b.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i=i+2) {
         System.out.println(b[i]+" " + b[i+1]); 
    }

}
```

Output

```
13131300100 999
13131300200 999
13131300300 999
13131300400 999
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. If 999 is your delimiter, you should split the string by " 999".

You can print the result as

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 

     String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 
     String delimiter = " 999";

     String[] b = a.split(delimiter); 
     for (String c : b) { 
         System.out.println(c.trim() + delimiter); 
     } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the space before the split

```
String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999";
a = a.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 

    String[] b = a.split(" "); 
    for (int i =0 ;i<b.length;i++) { 
        System.out.println("Value\t:" + b[i]+b[i+1]); 
        i++;
}
```

try like this

Answer (score 0):

```
   String a = "13131300100 999  13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s)+");  //handles one or more space
    String[] m = p.split(a);

    for(int i=0; i< m.length-1; i+=2){
        System.out.println(m[i]+" "+m[i+1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may fulfill your requirement

```
public class Demo { 

 public static void main(String[] args) { 

     String a = "13131300100 999 13131300200 999 13131300300 999 13131300400 999"; 

     StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(a);
     int i=0,spacecnt=0;
     while(i!=a.length()){
         if(a.charAt(i)==' '){
             spacecnt+=1;
             if(spacecnt%2==0)
                 myName.setCharAt(i, '\n');
         }
         i++;
     }
     System.out.println(myName);
 }
```

}

OUTPUT :

```
13131300100 999
13131300200 999
13131300300 999
13131300400 999
```